# Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-javadoc-plugin Java 16 with pattern matching

Tags: java, maven

I was playing around with new Java 16 features and when I wanted to build a local maven install I get this error:

```
Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-javadoc-plugin:3.2.0:jar (attach-javadocs) on project persism: MavenReportException: Error while generating Javadoc:

error: ')' expected
        if (object instanceof Persistable<?> pojo) {
```

Pointing to "pojo" variable. This works fine when I run and build in the IDE. I have other Java 16 features in the code like records as well.

My POM source and target are set to 16.

I notice it runs this:

exe /X /C "C:\Java\jdk1.8.0_231\bin\javadoc.exe @options @argfile"

why is it running Java 8?

Any ideas?

Comment: What feature is this? A variable name behind a type argument to the `instanceof` operator? What purpose does that fulfill?

Comment: Those variables don’t determine the JDK to use. It would seems that your JAVA_HOME is perhaps incorrect?

Comment: What is your maven configuration? Do share your pom and the relevant code segment as well.

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/394

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose it's the pattern matching feature of Java 16. When you have instanceof you can put a variable at the end so you don't have to cast for one.

Comment: @VGR Ah. Ok. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah I realized that Maven ran java 8 for the Javadoc. I set JAVA_HOME to my java 16 version. Problem solved.